Multiple Google OAuths Clients for a single application?
I am currently developing an application that incorporates three distinct roles: admin, employee, and candidate. We are utilizing Google OAuth for login purposes. However, a colleague suggested employing two separate OAuth clients for the same application. One client would have a consent screen configured to permit only internal emails, while the other would be for general use. When I inquired about the rationale behind this approach, he mentioned scalability as the primary reason. I would appreciate your insights on this matter.
Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Google recommends one production project per app.  If you have a development server should create a separate project for that version of the app.    There is no reason to have separate clients for different sets of users it just adds complexity to your system that you dont need.
